# My frontend and backend collapse , How can I fix

Tags: magento2.3

After I run the follow command to activate the Chinese language, it is collpased. How can I fix it ? [image]

[image]

Comment: provide us the command. read the documentation to the command. you probably just built the static files for chinese and this will throw away all static files for the other languages

Answer (score 0):

The command I run the command in Putty to access SSH is below

composer require astralweb/zh_hant_tw
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy zh_Hant_TW